# LaTeX: how to make a horizontal tree that is closed at the end (forest)

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, forest

I have created the following horizontal tree in LaTeX, using the forest package.

```
    \forestset{
  L1/.style={draw=black,},
  L2/.style={,edge={,line width=0.8pt}},
}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+1pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=8mm, % node shape
        l sep=10mm % level distance
    }
  [Some text,L1
    [Some text ,L2]
    [Some text,L2]
    [Some text,L2]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

It gives me the following output:

[image]

Now I would like to "close" the tree again, i.e. the following:

[image]

Any input on how to modify the code so that the tree "grows together" at the end would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set names to the nodes in the tree and draw the merge node by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  L1/.style={draw=black,},
  L2/.style={,edge={,line width=0.8pt}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
    parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
    edge={line cap=round},outer sep=+1pt, % edge/node connection
    rounded corners,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=8mm, % node shape
    l sep=10mm % level distance
  }
  [Some text,L1
  [Some text ,L2,name=ST1]
  [Some text,L2,name=ST2]
  [Some text,L2,name=ST3]
  ]
  \node[draw,rounded corners,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=8mm,anchor=west] (EndNode) at ($(ST2.east) + (1,0)$){Merge text};
  \foreach \num in {1,2,3}{
    \draw (ST\num.east) -- (EndNode.west);
  }
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gret-D You don't actually have to name the nodes. You could just specify them relatively.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to add the additional node as part of the tree and then add the additional edges, using that node's `edge` option. You can do this by naming nodes or, as here, using relative node names. You don't have to use the `tikz` key, but it simplifies matters if using relative node names as it means nodes are relative to whatever the current node happens to be. So `()` is the current node, `(!u)` is its parent, `(!up)` is its parent's previous sibling and so on. This means `() edge ...` will draw edges from 'here', wherever here happens to be.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  L1/.style={draw=black},
  L2/.style={line width=0.8pt, line cap=round},
}%
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    edge+=L2,
    outer sep=+1pt,
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=15mm,
    minimum height=8mm,
    l sep'=10mm,
  }
  [Some text, L1
    [Some text, L2]
    [Some text, L2
      [\phantom{Some text}, L1, tikz+/.process={Ow1{edge}{\draw [#1] (.child anchor) edge (!un.parent anchor) -- (!up.parent anchor);}}]
    ]
    [Some text, L2]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: symmetrical ending]